# How can I apply certain rules to certain columns in JDBC?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I have a unique problem here. I have around 1k columns in various tables spread across multiple databases which are `Latin1` in MySQL.

And the user can enter anything in the parameters. I used the following solution in the Database class to fix it for a few columns:

```
 String output = input.replaceAll("[^\\u0020-\\u007e\\u00a0-\\u00ff]", " ");
```

But now I need to do it for all the 1k+ columns. Is there a shortcut to do this?

Can I put this logic directly in the MySQL so whenever it runs a query, it checks for the values for those particular columns?

I also cannot change the database column types in MySQL, so it has to be checked during runtime.

Comment: Check database triggers for that https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: @Ivan I was actually trying to avoid triggers. Instead I was looking for a Java based solution.

Comment: Then you may need to create a wrapper around `DataSource` and `Connection` to override method `setString(index, value)` to replace characters.

Comment: @Ivan Yeah, but even then I will need to catch the feedback in all the classes. Though of doing that, but I guess that's the best way.